# Dynamically change the path of an animateMotion SVG element on event

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to , for a specific event, such as onclick, as a specific SVG element, change that SVG's `animateMotion` element and play that animation again. My current code does replay the animation correctly, but does not change the path attribute

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SVG Example</title>
    <style>
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<script>
  window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var dot = document.getElementById("reddot");
     dot.path = 'M 0 0 H ' + (e.clientX) + ' V ' + (e.clientY);
     dot.beginElement();
  });
</script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="2" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" id="reddot" repeatCount="1" path="M 0 0 H 10 V 10" restart="always" />
  </circle>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Clicking multiple times plays the animation multiple times, yet `path` does not change. The specific goal of this is to create an animation where the animation moves to where the mouse was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM class of `<animateMotion` is `SVGAnimateMotionElement`.  That class has no `path` property ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimateMotionElement)).  So `dot.path = "..."` is doing nothing.

Use `dot.setAttribute("path", "...")` instead.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var dot = document.getElementById("reddot");
     dot.setAttribute("path", 'M 0 0 H ' + (e.clientX) + ' V ' + (e.clientY));
     dot.beginElement();
  });
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="2" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" id="reddot" repeatCount="1" path="M 0 0 H 10 V 10" restart="always" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```